# CouchDb GET _session not setting the cookie header from the browser in Angular7

Tags: angular, authentication, cookies, couchdb

I have an angular 7 application doing authentication with Couchdb. The cookie is getting set in the browser while doing POST _session with credentials. But again while doing GET _session for checking the authentication status the cookie is not set automatically even after using `withCredentials: true` in the POST header.

The POST request:

```
    let _httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    _httpHeaders = _httpHeaders.set('Accept', 'application/json');
    _httpHeaders = _httpHeaders.set('Content-type', 'application/json');
    _httpHeaders = _httpHeaders.set('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa(data.name + ':' + data.password));
    const options = { headers: _httpHeaders, withCredentials: true };
    console.log(options);
    return this._httpService.doAsyncTask(AppConstants.LOGIN_URL, 'POST', data, options);
```

The GET request:

```
 return this._httpService.doAsyncTask(AppConstants.LOGIN_URL + '?basic=true', 'GET');
```

Setting `withCredentials: true` in the header for the GET request also does not work.

The response I am getting:

> {"error":"unauthorized","reason":"Please login."}

The request and response headers for the GET call:
Request Header:

```
 Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
    Origin: http://localhost:5800
    Referer: http://localhost:5800/login
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36
```

Response Header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:5800
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: content-type, cache-control, accept-ranges, etag, server, x-couch-request-id, x-couch-update-newrev, x-couchdb-body-time
Cache-Control: must-revalidate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 50
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Fri, 14 Jun 2019 09:41:31 GMT
Server: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
X-Couch-Request-ID: 3fb687405b
X-CouchDB-Body-Time: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. The `withCredentials: true` header needs to be set the GET request. The correct way to send it is:

```
    let _httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    _httpHeaders = _httpHeaders.set('Accept', 'application/json');
    _httpHeaders = _httpHeaders.set('Content-type', 'application/json');
    const options = { headers: _httpHeaders, withCredentials: true };
    return this._httpService.doAsyncTask(AppConstants.LOGIN_URL + '?basic=true', 'GET', '', options);
```

In response you will get the userCtx object.

```
{"ok":true,"userCtx":{"name":"username","roles":["sales"]},"info":{"authentication_db":"_users","authentication_handlers":["cookie","default"],"authenticated":"cookie"}}
```

I hope this helps someone with the same problem.